# Copy multiple rows and columns from multiple tables into one table Excel

Tags: excel

I need to copy multiple rows and columns from multiple tables into one table, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this. All tables have the same header (same variables).

My case:

- Table 1 is the main table I want to populate.
- Table 2 has 20 rows (constantly growing) with 50 columns (constantly growing).
- Table 3 has 50 rows (constantly growing) with 50 columns (constantly growing).
- Table 4 has 100 rows (constantly growing) with 50 columns (constantly growing).
- Table 5 has 250 rows (constantly growing) with 50 columns (constantly growing).

For table 1, I would like to copy each of the rows from the other tables into it.

Example: I would like all of the rows from table 2 copied to table 1, then right underneath table 2's data copy all of the rows from table 3 to table 1, etc.

If possible I would also like to be able to specify which columns are copied. The columns copied will be the same on all of them.

Example: I want to copy columns A, B, and D, but not C from each of the tables to table 1.

Answer (score 0):

- Highlight cells/rows
- CTRL+C (copy)
- Open new sheet/file
- CTRL+V (paste)
- Sort or Apply Filters

ba-da bing, ba-da boom.